# Nested Header Implementation Using AbstractGroupsModel and List box(like Grid hierarchy demo))

Tags: listbox, zk, listitem

I want to design Nested Header (for group header and data header related to group.)
Means I want to design like this . The top header will be there, once I will click on the header the sub header data will come (The sub header will contain one header and some record data.) [image]

I have written the code like this

```
   <template name="model:group" var="group">
          <listgroup label="@load(groupNameList)"
          style="color: #666;" open="false"
          onClick="@command('groupCloseAndOpen',listGroup = self)"
          tooltiptext="@load(each)">
              <listcell>
                  <label  value="${group.deptId}"                                                    tooltiptext="${each.deptId}">
                  </label>
              </listcell>
              <listcell>
                <label  value="${group.deptName}"
                        tooltiptext="${each.deptName}">
               </label>
              </listcell>
              <listcell>
                    <label value="${group.deptLoc}"
                          tooltiptext="${each.deptLoc}">
                    </label>
              </listcell>
                    </listgroup>
            </template>

            <template name="model" var="folderInfoData">
                <listitem>  
                <listcell if="${folderInfoDataStatus.index == 0}">
                        <label                                  
                            value="@load(folderInfoData.id)"/>
                            </listcell>                     
                    <listcell>
                        <label                                 
                            value="@load(folderInfoData.id)"/>
                            </listcell>
                        <listcell><label                                    
                            value="@load(folderInfoData.name)" />
                            </listcell>
                        <listcell><label
                            value="@load(folderInfoData.sal)"
                             />
                    </listcell>                         
                </listitem>
            </template>

        </listbox>
```

Can anyone suggest how to solve this issue ?

Comment: I'm thinking you need a listbox into the second template to solve this. A static header in each group isn't provided by default by ZK.

Comment: ok. let me try . Actually I have one listbox  , inside that  i have used 2 template , so according to your idea I need to use listbox inside the template . This is what u want to mention @chillworld

Comment: Yes, but because you use a groupsmodel the second template doesn't get a "list" of items but you get one item multiple times. If it was me I think I should go for grid with detail and add listbox in the detail. model of grid contains collections and use the collections to the listboxes.